# Reset HP switch login credentials

Tags: switch

I am new to hardware side of networking, my overall purpose is to introduce VLAN to a LAN network.

To do this I have connected my router/pfsense to main-switch (my switch:HP1920-48G JG927A) and main-switch is connected to other switchs.

When this was purchased the previous worker configured some password (I think) and now no one knows what the password is in our company.

I heard I can reset the password by holding a reset button but this switch have no buttons? does this means I can never reset login credentials for this switch?

Can someone advice please?

UPDATE:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This device is a Comware based switch, so the front panel reset buttons are not available.  To reset the password you will need to connect a console cable (38400/8/N/1), reboot the switch, then press Ctrl + B during boot up (similar to Cisco ROMMON).  You will then have an option to boot the switch without a configuration, which will also have no password.

See this guide for further details:

http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=mmr_sf-EN_US000005130

Comment: My login credentials was default as shown on your link. So, now I can access the switch but it only provides me with few options (image uploaded in question), how can I create VLANS etc... also if I create VLAN's and make any port a trunk can this affect the production network? (at the moment there is nothing configured in this switch)

Comment: You need to configure an IP address and then connect to the switch with a web browser and configure it from there

Comment: I have pfsense and router connected to that switch. Configuring ip will that cause any issue to pfsense (i.e will pfsense be able to talk to switch?) if something goes wrong and can i just restart the switch? (this will remove any configured settings as i would have not saved them).